# Is this the right method for distributing a python app with git and pip?

Tags: python, git, pip, python-packaging, python-venv

I write python applications for internal use at my company. Everyone has python installed on their machines, but they are not developers, so cloning a repo or creating a venv is outside of their skillset. I was hoping to change my apps so they may update themselves when I push an update to the git repo on a shared network drive. I would like the app code to update, but also the dependencies installed in each of their virtual environments.

I was thinking of wrapping my application in some code which, before importing any of the dependencies:

1. Checks if a venv exists

   - if it doesn't, creates one using the local requirements.txt
   - if it does, skips this step
2. Checks if the git repo version tag is more recent than the local git repo version tag

   - if a more recent version is available, it will pull from the master repo. The repo will only contain the app code and the requirements.txt

     - It will then `pip install --upgrade` the new or updated packages using the new requirements.txt file
   - if a newer version isn't available, it just runs the app

This all seems doable, and not terribly complicated, but I can't help but feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here. This seems a bit too manual and too common of a problem for there not to be a better way of doing this. What am I missing? What's the best way to handle this? Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: `pipenv`? `pipx`? `PyInstaller`? `py2exe`?

Comment: You mind expanding on that a little bit?

Comment: `pipenv` and `pipx` create virtual environment on the fly; `pipx` creates virtualenv specifically for a script. `PyInstaller`, `py2exe`, `cx_Freeze` combine a script with its dependencies into a standalone executable so you can distribute the executable (and dependencies) to persons that don't have Python, and the recipients don't need to create virtualenvs or install dependencies.

Comment: Pipenv just automates venv creation, pipx seems like it's for CL tools, and executable files don't even address the original problem. I can get software to these people. That's not hard. I'm trying to figure out an elegant way of pushing updates to these people.